# null or undefined check in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, null, local-storage, undefined

I am caching a string in my `localStorage`

```
 checkLoop:function(){   //function is hit only if internet is connected
 localStorage['key'] = "Some string response from web service";
 //JSON Web service could return null, "" (empty response) too
 }
```

This key would be defined only when there is internet connection. So there are chances that my function `checkLoop` is never been hit. i.e localStorage is never defined.

Later I have a check to see if it is `defined` or `null`

So making a check like `if(!localStorage['key']){..//TODO..}` would work?

Or I need to customize it more for better code?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!localStorage['key']){
    // Will enter if the value is null\undefined\false\0\""
}
```

You might want to use this instead:

```
if(localStorage['key'] == null){
    // only null\undefined.
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Z322/)

Falsy values in javascript are:

- undefined
- null
- false
- 0
- "" - (Empty string)

Answer (score 0):

Use `typeof`

```
if(typeof localStorage['key'] !== 'undefined'){ 
    // Do Something 
}
```

**Note:** This is useful if you want to store `false` or `0` values.